# AWS shows 404 page when deploying new angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-amplify

I created a new angular app ng new my-project --directory ./ --routing hosted on github.

When I deployed it to aws amplify, I just get a 404 error page.

The project shows up fine locally

What am I missing

I don't know what else to try

EDIT: I needed to update the path in the build file on AWS